# jQuery width (%) doesn't stop calculate on windowResize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

This is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/7cXZj/

```
    var callback = function () {

  $('.progress-bar').width($('.progress-bar').parent().width() - 190);


  $(".mainpart-background").animate({ width: "80%" }, 800 , function(){
    var sidepartposition = $(".progress-bar").width() * 0.1 + $(".sidepart-content").width() * 0.5 ;
   $(".sidepart").animate({ "margin-right": - sidepartposition }, 100); 
   });

};
$(document).ready(callback);
$(window).resize(callback);


var sidepartpositionResize = $(".progress-bar").width() * 0.1 + $(".sidepart-content").width() * 0.5 ;

$(window).resize(function(){

   $(".sidepart").css( "margin-right", "sidepartpositionResize" );

});
```

This is the problem:

The span showing "20%" disappears when you resize the window. Why? Inspecting it with Firebug you will see jQuery won't stop calculate the 80%, it goes 80.00213 to 79.1241 to 79.12523 ... and so on. Suddenly after 1-4 seconds it's done with this strange process. Then the span contents the 20% appears.

Please note: This code should work on responsive websites.

I'm a JS beginner. Thank you so much for help!

Comment: Did my answer suit you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code: http://jsfiddle.net/7cXZj/5/

This code lets you bind to the end of the resize event and not executing the function many times during the resize of the window.

```
var animate = function(){
console.log('animando');
$(".mainpart-background").css('width', 0);
$(".mainpart-background").animate({
        width: "80%"
    }, 800, function () {
        var sidepartposition = $(".progress-bar").width() * 0.1 + $(".sidepart-content").width() * 0.5;

        $(".sidepart").animate({
            "margin-right": -sidepartposition
        }, 10);
    }
);    
}

window.resizeEvt;

$(document).ready(function(){
animate();

$(window).resize(function()
{
    clearTimeout(window.resizeEvt);
    window.resizeEvt = setTimeout(function()
    {
        animate();
    }, 250);
});
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please try to explain what changes you made and why they should fix this issue.

Comment: I wrote it: This code lets you bind to the end of the resize event and not executing the function many times during the resize of the window.

Comment: If you see the ready function, you'll see the change. If you get into the jsfiddle and execute, you'll see its working. Just go ahead.